# How to filter a custom listView with text, image and checkbox?

Tags: java, android, listview-filter

Watching a tutorial I have a `listView`.

I have an `EditText` and want to filter the listView content by what is in the EditText.

Here is my adapter class:

```
class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> FriendsExceptList;
    private Context context;
    ListViewAdapter(Context context, List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> FriendsExceptList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.FriendsExceptList = FriendsExceptList;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return FriendsExceptList.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int pos) {
        return FriendsExceptList.get(pos);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int pos) {
        return pos;
    }
    @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.model,viewGroup,false);

        TextView name = view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ImageView avatar = view.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
        final CheckBox checkbox = view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);

        final listAudienceFriendsExcept thisListAudienceFriendsExcept = FriendsExceptList.get(position);

        // Setting data to listView items
        checkbox.setTag(thisListAudienceFriendsExcept.getId());
        name.setText(thisListAudienceFriendsExcept.getGetFirstName());
        if (!thisListAudienceFriendsExcept.getGetAvatar().equals("default_avatar.png")) {
            Glide.with(avatar)
                    .load(API_BASE_URL+"files/avatar_back_files/"+thisListAudienceFriendsExcept.getGetAvatar())
                    .circleCrop()
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(avatar);
        } else if (thisListAudienceFriendsExcept.getGetSex().equals("male")) {
            Glide.with(avatar)
                    .load(API_BASE_URL+"tools/img/default_avatar.png")
                    .circleCrop()
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(avatar);
        } else {
            Glide.with(avatar)
                    .load(API_BASE_URL+"tools/img/female_default_avatar.png")
                    .circleCrop()
                    .fitCenter()
                    .into(avatar);
        }
        return view;
    }
}
```

Here my list:

```
static class listAudienceFriendsExcept {
    @SerializedName("id")
    private int id;
    @SerializedName("first_name")
    private String first_name;
    @SerializedName("last_name")
    private String last_name;
    @SerializedName("avatar")
    private String avatar;
    @SerializedName("sex")
    private String sex;

    public listAudienceFriendsExcept(int id, String first_name, String last_name, String avatar, String sex) {
        this.id = id;
        this.first_name = first_name;
        this.last_name = last_name;
        this.avatar = avatar;
        this.sex = sex;
    }
    int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    String getGetFirstName() {
        return first_name;
    }
    String getGetLastName() {
        return last_name;
    }
    String getGetAvatar() {
        return avatar;
    }
    String getGetSex() {
        return sex;
    }
}
```

Here my populateListView:

```
private void populateListView(List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> thisList) {
    ListView listViewAudienceFriendsExcept = findViewById(R.id.listViewAudienceFriendsExcept);
    ListViewAdapter adapter = new ListViewAdapter(this, thisList);
    listViewAudienceFriendsExcept.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I tried that:

```
final TextInputEditText first_name_edit_text = findViewById(R.id.first_name_edit_text);


    first_name_edit_text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int s, int b, int c) {

              friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText); // What is **friendListAdapter** in my case ?
        }
```

I'm using Retrofit tho get data from server when activity start:

```
private void callServer() {
    /*Create handle for the RetrofitInstance interface*/
    df myAPIService = RetrofitClientInstance.getRetrofitInstance().create(df.class);

    Call<List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>> call = myAPIService.getListAudienceFriendsExcept();
    call.enqueue(new Callback<List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>>() {

        @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>> call, Response<List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>> response) {
             populateListView(response.body());
        }
        @SuppressWarnings("NullableProblems")
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>> call, Throwable throwable) {
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, throwable.getMessage()+"èèè", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

I have googled and found that: **friendListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);** But I don't know to use in my case.

Any Solution?

My other question:
**How could I pass the user ID to php server ?**

Thanks.`

Answer (score 0):

You can use streams to filter.

```
 //add this imports on your class or activity
//import com.annimon.stream.Collectors;
//import com.annimon.stream.Stream;
//import com.annimon.stream.function.Predicate;




List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> original_list=new ArrayList<>();
List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> search_list=new ArrayList<>();
EditText serch_field;
void setup()
{
 //original_list=whatever the source of the list is
 //be sure to populate the original list before proceeding here
    populateListView(original_list);

    serch_field.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            search_list =  Stream.of(original_list).filter(new Predicate<listAudienceFriendsExcept>() {
                @Override
                public boolean test(listAudienceFriendsExcept item) {
                    //  return item.getGetFirstName().toUpperCase().contains(serch_field.getText().toString().toUpperCase())||item.getGetLastName().toUpperCase().contains(serch_field.getText().toString().toUpperCase());//if  you want to filter multiple fields
                    return item.first_name.toUpperCase().contains(serch_field.getText().toString().toUpperCase());//to filter first name only
                }
            }).collect(com.annimon.stream.Collectors.<listAudienceFriendsExcept>toList());

            populateListView(search_list);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

   }
```

For the model

```
public class listAudienceFriendsExcept {
@SerializedName("id")
private int id;
@SerializedName("first_name")
public String first_name;
@SerializedName("last_name")
private String last_name;
@SerializedName("avatar")
private String avatar;
@SerializedName("sex")
private String sex;

public listAudienceFriendsExcept(int id, String first_name, String last_name, String avatar, String sex) {
    this.id = id;
    this.first_name = first_name;
    this.last_name = last_name;
    this.avatar = avatar;
    this.sex = sex;
}
int getId() {
    return id;
}
 public String getGetFirstName() {
    return first_name;
 }
 public String getGetLastName() {
    return last_name;
  }
  public String getGetAvatar() {
    return avatar;
 }
 public String getGetSex() {
    return sex;
}
}
```

And on Gradle-dependencies add

```
 implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.2'
```

Comment: No idea how to use your answer. Using these: `List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> original_list=new   List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>();
    List<listAudienceFriendsExcept> search_list=new List<listAudienceFriendsExcept>(); `give error: "List" is abstract cannot be instantiated.

Comment: When I try to run, I see: `MainActivity.java:86: error: package com.annimon.stream does not exist
                }).collect(com.annimon.stream.Collectors.<listAudienceFriendsExcept>toList());`; It seems like your code is for API minimum 24. My minimum API is 21.

Comment: Near: `Stream.of(original_list).filter(new Predicate<listAudienceFriendsExcept>() { ` **.of** is red marked. Error: `Static interface methode calls are not supported at langage level 7. Thanks for help.`

Comment: on gradle  implementation 'com.annimon:stream:1.1.2'
    minSdkVersion 21 and import com.annimon.stream.Collectors;
on your class import com.annimon.stream.Stream;
import com.annimon.stream.function.Predicate;

Comment: All error has gone but how to use the `setup()`: Methode `setup()` is new used. Please be clear I'm learner.

Comment: App is lanching but Nothing happened when I tap characters.

Comment: do not import java.util.stream.Stream; use com.annimon.stream .java.util.stream will bring that error.Call the setup method after you have populated your original list and instantiated your Edittext

Comment: "after you have populated your original list and instantiated your Edittext" Where in `Oncreate` ? I must `create` the `addTextChangedListener` in Oncreate ? Any example for the beginner :::)))